# Xamarin.Forms upload image to server directory

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I have to upload an image from my application to a php web service i tried this code:

```
private void  upload(MediaFile mediaFile)
{
    try
    {   
        byte[] data = ReadFully(mediaFile.Source);

        var imageStream = new ByteArrayContent(data);
        imageStream.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".Png"
        };

        var multi = new MultipartContent();
        multi.Add(imageStream);
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("url");
        var result = client.PostAsync("api/ManageImage", multi).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $uploads_dir = 'Image/'; //Directory to save the file that comes from 
    client application.      
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)       
    {      
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];     
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];    
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");   
    }
?>
```

i take the file with Xam.Plugin.FilePicker but i don't know how to send and how to recive the image

Comment: "I tried this code" - and?  Did it work?  Throw an exception?  Crash?  Give an error?  Please be more specific about the problem that you're encountering.  Keep in mind that an image is just a bunch of bytes like any other file, so an image upload is really no different than a general file upload.

Comment: i know this code don't work i need to take an image from internal/external storage and upload it to my server directory like var/www/upload.I need both php and c# help.

Comment: The PHP part is right, but de C#, you need to send the same "input" name that you capture in PHP (in PHP is file, and in C# is attachment...